# WatchKit Extension Bridging Header errors (in Swift Project)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm using the `Parse` framework in my project,

[image]

It works fine with no errors in my main app `Bridging-Header` above,

[image]

but when I try to use it in my **WatchKit Extension `Bridging-Header`** I get all kinds of **errors**.

[image]

Any ideas why this would be happening?  I'd like to use `Parse` framework in my Watch App.

*This is a Swift project, and I created the Bridging Headers by just adding a dummy Objective-C file named `Misc`.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

watchOS does not have the same frameworks as iOS. You will not be able to use the Parse SDK in WatchKit.

Comment: Hmmm.  I've been using `Parse` in my original WatchKit extension `InterfaceController.m` to do a `Parse` query, so I guess I'm confused.  Did something change where I'm not able to do that anymore?  Or now that it is watchOS2 and not the original watchOS1, you aren't able to use the `Parse` framework?

Comment: Most likely the differences in watchOS 2. The model parts should work fine, but not the view parts. Only a subset of UIKit is available in WatchKit 2 (eg no UIButton).